# Apidata in Array but array data not show in textbox

Tags: ios

```
NSString *stringForTextView = @"";



for(NSDictionary *d in _arr1)
{
    stringForTextView = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellId:%@\nLacId:%@\nLattitude:%@\nLongitude:%@\nDistance:%@\nAddress:%@\n", [d valueForKey:@"cid"],[d valueForKey:@"lac"],[d valueForKey:@"lat"], [d valueForKey:@"long"], [d valueForKey:@"distance"],[d valueForKey:@"address"]];
}



txtcellview.text = stringForTextView;
```

only last record show....all record not show in textview

apidata in arr but arry data not show in textbox

Comment: Append the text to `stringForTextView` instead of recreating each time.

Answer (score 0):

"only last record show...."

That's because you are constantly assigning the same variable, each iteration of the loop and so whatever was assigned last will remain.

I'm not certain what you want, but you probably want to keep appending each element to a string:

```
NSMutableString *stringForTextView = [NSMutableString new];
for(NSDictionary *d in _arr1)
{
    [stringForTextView appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellId:%@\nLacId:%@\nLattitude:%@\nLongitude:%@\nDistance:%@\nAddress:%@\n", [d valueForKey:@"cid"],[d valueForKey:@"lac"],[d valueForKey:@"lat"], [d valueForKey:@"long"], [d valueForKey:@"distance"],[d valueForKey:@"address"]]];
}
txtcellview.text = stringForTextView;
```

Note that this code does not add a delimiter between elements; I'll leave that to you...